# i5 with gpu vs i7 without gpu which is better

Tags: laptop, graphics-cards, gaming, pc, intel

Is core i7 10th (10710U) gen 16gb ram with uhd graphics better or core i5 10th (10500H) gen 8gb ram with 4gb GTX 1650 for like pentesting and sone GTA 5 and csgo and call of duty asking for laptops like msi gf63 thin is core i5 and dell xps 13 7390 is i7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are going to be gaming, a dedecated GPU is (almost) always better than none. If the i5 only has 8GB RAM, you do need to manually upgrade it to 16GB, because gaming on 8GB is a little tight (except light games like Minecraft and CSGO on Linux)

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, Discrete GPU will be better for gaming, at least in this case. So its a toss up, either get better cpu with the i7 or better gpu with the i5.